# Where is the aws key management plugin for MariaDB on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, mariadb

I followed the instructions here https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aws-key-management-encryption-plugin-setup-guide/#installation and added the appropriate repository for MariaDB to my Ubuntu 18.04 installation. I then tried to install the aws key management plugin, but that package can't be found. I've spent a lot of time on Google trying to figure out where it is, and I still can't figure out how to install it.

Has anyone run into this issue and/or does anyone know how I can get this plugin installed? I've downloaded the list of packages and can't find anything related to aws.

Comment: Only the following packages seem to be available in the repos the documentation says should include the aws plugin: mariadb-plugin-connect, mariadb-plugin-cracklib-password-check, mariadb-plugin-gssapi-client, mariadb-plugin-gssapi-server, mariadb-plugin-mroonga, mariadb-plugin-oqgraph, mariadb-plugin-tokudb, mariadb-plugin-rocksdb, mariadb-plugin-spider

Comment: More digging reveals that while this plugin once existed in the repos but mysteriously went missing for 10.3, the repos for 10.2 appear to still contain the plugin. I'm going to use 10.2 for now, but if anyone can shed some light on why I can't find it for 10.3, that would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional. Unfortunately we cannot distribute aws_key_management plugin — the fact that we did before was a mistake.

This plugin uses (and is linked with) AWS C++ SDK, which is available under the Apache 2.0 license. And this license it not compatible with GPLv2.

You can build this plugin yourself by using the cmake option -DNOT_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=1, the plugin wil be built and you'll get a warning that the result is not GPL and cannot be distributed.

If we'll find a replacement for AWS C++ SDK that uses a GPLv2 compatible license, we will be able to switch to it and distribute the plugin again.

[Reference](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-18752?jql=project%20%3D%20MDEV%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22Plugin%20-%20AWS%20key%20management%22)

Comment: That's too bad, but I understand about the licensing issues. I'll investigate installing MariaDB from my OS's repos and the plugin from source.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to put together the pieces to compile the aws_key_management plugin from source on CentOS 7.

**install build dependencies**

```
yum-builddep -y mariadb-server
yum install -y git \
    gcc \
    gcc-c++ \
    bison \
    libxml2-devel \
    libevent-devel \
    rpm-build
```

**download MariaDB source**

```
cd /usr/local/src
git clone --branch 10.3 https://github.com/MariaDB/server.git
```

**run CMake to read MariaDB for the build**

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/build-mariadb
cd /usr/local/src/build-mariadb
cmake -DRPM=centos7 \
      -DPLUGIN_AWS_KEY_MANAGEMENT=DYNAMIC \
      -DAWS_SDK_EXTERNAL_PROJECT=1 \
      -DNOT_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=1 \
      ../server
```

**build MariaDB**

```
make aws_key_management
```

**copy aws_key_management plugin**

```
cp ./plugin/aws_key_management/aws_key_management.so \
   /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/aws_key_management.so
```

Comment: I just posted an Ubuntu-specific list of steps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55251366/4683164) based on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OracleJavaNet's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55083209/4683164), I've put together my own mini tutorial for Ubuntu (tested on 16.04 and 18.04):

## Part 1. Install MariaDB

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xF1656F24C74CD1D8
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,arm64,ppc64el] http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.3/ubuntu bionic main'
```

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list and uncomment the deb-src line for the repo (at the bottom of the file)

```
apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-client-10.3 mariadb-server-10.3
```

## Part 2. Install aws_key_management plugin

Note that setting DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS to c++11 instead of gnu++11 results in compile errors!

```
sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev uuid-dev libssl-dev
cd /tmp && sudo apt-get source mariadb-server-10.3
cd /tmp/mariadb-10.3*
sudo cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=gnu++11 -DPLUGIN_AWS_KEY_MANAGEMENT=DYNAMIC -DAWS_SDK_EXTERNAL_PROJECT=1 -DNOT_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=1
sudo make aws_key_management
sudo cp -R /tmp/mariadb*/plugin/aws_key_management/aws_key_management.so /usr/lib/mysql/plugin && chmod 644 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/aws_key_management.so
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you that use Docker, I created a [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/creemama/mariadb-aws_key_management-plugin-build) that builds the AWS Key Management Plugin from source. The resulting `aws_key_management.so` is compatible with the [Docker official images for MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb).

To make `aws_key_management.so`, do the following:

```
docker run --name aws_key_management_build creemama/mariadb-aws_key_management-plugin-build:latest
docker cp aws_key_management_build:/usr/local/src/build-mariadb/plugin/aws_key_management/aws_key_management.so .
```

Examine the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/creemama/docker/blob/master/mariadb-aws_key_management-plugin-build/10.3/Dockerfile) for the steps used to build the plugin.